# How to create a dynamic learning rate per neuron in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, neural-network, pytorch, learning-rate

I know it's possible to have a learning rate per layer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801648/how-to-apply-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-pytorch)). I also found how to dynamically change the learning rate (changing it in the middle of training dynamically without a scheduler) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324152/pytorch-how-to-change-the-learning-rate-of-an-optimizer-at-any-given-moment-no/64453694)).

How can I create an optimizer that will have a dynamic learning rate **per neuron**? So that I could change the value of the learning rate for specific neurons during training

As an example, if my network is as follows:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3,5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5,10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
        return x
```

There should be 5 learning rates for the first layer (one for each of the 5 neurons, where each neuron has 3 associated weights), 10 for the second layer, and 1 for the last one.

Comment: Is a fully connected layer implemented as a matrix calculation in Pytorch? `out=activation(xW+b)`? Maybe a "per-neuron" learning rate would use a vector or matrix element-wise rate multiplier instead of a scalar when updating `W`? For me the idea of "per-neuron" is a little confusing when the matrix multiplication is the whole layer.

Comment: @xdhmoore I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: you can manually do backward by doing `loss.backward()` and then `layer_W = layer_W - learning_rate * layer_W.grad`. Learning rate is just a multiplier to the gradient. So instead of multiplying by a single float `learning_rate`, you can multiply `layer_W.grad` by an array with each neurons lr